# ODEs with infinite initlal condition in python

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I have a second order differential equation that I want to solve it in python. The problem is that for one of the variables I don't have the initial condition in `0` but only the value at infinity. Can one tell me what parameters I should provide for `scipy.integrate.odeint` ? Can it be solved?

Equation:
[image]

Theta needs to be found in terms of time. Its first derivative is equal to zero at `t=0`. theta is not known at `t=0` but it goes to zero at sufficiently large time. all the rest is known. As an approximate `I` can be set to zero, thus removing the second order derivative which should make the problem easier.

Comment: You can find the answer from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824751/infinity-generated-in-python-code

Comment: You cannot give `scipy.integrate.odeint` conditions at two different values of `t`. If instead of a second condition at infinity, you had it at `t = t1`, you could nest your solution with `scipy.integrate.odeint` inside a call to `scipy.optimize.root` to find the value of tetha at `t = 0` that gave you the desired behavior at `t = t1`. Maybe choosing a large enough `t1` would allow you to use that idea. You may also want to try http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ for help figuring the right strategy to tackle your problem.

Comment: @Jaime, Could you please provide a rough answer by using `scipy.optimize.root` and predicting `t1` value?

Answer (score 4):

This is far from being a full answer, but is posted here on the OP's request.

The method I described in the comment is what is known as a [shooting method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method), that allows converting a boundary value problem into an initial value problem. For convenience, I am going to rename your function `theta` as `y`. To solve your equation numerically, you would first turn it into a first order system, using two auxiliary function, `z1 = y` and `z2 = y'`, and so your current equation

```
I y'' + g y' + k y = f(y, t)
```

would be rewitten as the system

```
z1' = z2
z2' = f(z1, t) - g z2 - k z1
```

and your boundary conditions are

```
z1(inf) = 0
z2(0) = 0
```

So first we set up the function to compute the derivative of your new vectorial function:

```
def deriv(z, t) :
    return np.array([z[1],
                     f(z[0], t) - g * z[1] - k * z[0]])
```

If we had a condition `z1[0] = a` we could solve this numerically between `t = 0` and `t = 1000`, and get the value of `y` at the last time as something like

```
def y_at_inf(a) :
    return scipy.integrate.odeint(deriv, np.array([a, 0]),
                                  np.linspace(0, 1000, 10000))[0][-1, 0]
```

So now all we need to know is what value of `a` makes `y = 0` at `t = 1000`, our poor man's infinity, with

```
a = scipy.optimize.root(y_at_inf, [1])
```

Comment: I haven't read in detail, but what I typically do with equations like that is solve them backward from the stationary state back to the past, running time backwards, i.e. ``t --> - \infty``